# Migrating Hibernate 3.2.5 to 3.6

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently We are facing a lot of problem in migrating our Application from Hibernate 3.2.5 to 3.6.1.

The first error that We are facing is :

SEVERE: Invalid column name 'btn_name'. Although btn_name is mapped no where. The actual mapping is btnName.

Here is my mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class abstract="true" name="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.Component"
        table="component_master">
        <id column="metadata_id" name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property column="metadata_type" name="type" type="string" />
        <property name="createdDateTime" column="created_date" type="date"
            update="false"></property>
        <property name="version" type="string" column="version_id"></property>
        <property name="currentDate" type="date" column="curr_date"></property>
        <property name="currentIP" type="string" column="current_ip"></property>
        <many-to-one name="currentUser"
            class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.domain.common.User" cascade="refresh"
            column="current_user_id"></many-to-one>
        <property name="latestDate" type="date" column="latest_date"></property>
        <property name="latestIP" type="string" column="latest_ip"></property>
        <many-to-one name="latestUser"
            class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.domain.common.User" cascade="refresh"
            column="latest_user"></many-to-one>
        <property name="recordStatus" type="boolean" column="record_status"></property>
        <property name="portal" type="string" column="portal"></property>
        <many-to-one cascade="refresh,save-update,delete"
            class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.Component" column="md_id"
            name="metadata" not-null="false" />

        <joined-subclass
            name="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.uicontrols.UIControl"
            table="ui_control_master">
            <key column="ui_control_id" />
            <property column="display_name" name="displayText" />
            <property column="help_text" name="helpText" />
            <property column="info_text" name="informativeText" />
            <property column="rows" name="rows" type="integer" />
            <property column="cols" name="cols" type="integer" />
            <property column="btnName" name="btnName" type="string" />
            <property name="version" type="string" column="version_id"></property>
            <property name="currentDate" type="date" column="curr_date"></property>
            <property name="currentIP" type="string" column="current_ip"></property>
            <many-to-one name="currentUser"
                class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.domain.common.User" cascade="refresh"
                column="current_user_id"></many-to-one>
            <property name="latestDate" type="date" column="latest_date"></property>
            <property name="latestIP" type="string" column="latest_ip"></property>
            <many-to-one name="latestUser"
                class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.domain.common.User" cascade="refresh"
                column="latest_user"></many-to-one>
            <property name="recordStatus" type="boolean" column="record_status"></property>
            <property name="portal" type="string" column="portal"></property>
            <property name="readOnly" type="boolean" column="read_only"/>

            <joined-subclass
                name="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.uicontrols.InputControl"
                table="input_control_master" lazy="true">
                <key column="input_control_id" />
                <property column="default_value" name="defaultValue"
                    not-null="false" />
                <property column="is_fk" name="fk" />
                <property column="validatable" name="validatable" />
                <property column="violatable" name="violatable" />
                <property name="isRequired" column="is_required"></property>
                <property name="ruleType"
                    type="com.sampleproject.facadeimplementation.util1.UserEnumRuleType"
                    column="rule_type"></property>
                <property name="fileType" column="file_type"></property>
                <property name="maxFileSize" column="max_file_size" type="integer"></property>
                <property name="precision" column="input_precision" type="integer"></property>
                <property name="maxLength" column="maxlength" type="integer"></property>
                <property name="minLength" column="minlength" type="integer"></property>
                <property name="dateFormatType" column="dateformat"
                    type="com.sampleproject.facadeimplementation.util1.UserEnumDateFormatType"></property>
                <property name="specialCharAllow" column="isspecialcharallow"></property>
                <property name="specialChars" column="specialchars" type="string"></property>
                <property name="dateType"
                    type="com.sampleproject.facadeimplementation.util1.UserEnumDateType"
                    column="date_type"></property>
                <property name="minDate" column="mindate" type="string"></property>
                <property name="maxDate" column="maxdate" type="string"></property>
                <property name="inspection" column="inspection" type="boolean"></property>
                <property name="values" column="default_values" type="string"></property>
                <property name="targetNames" column="target_names" type="string"></property>
                <!--
                    <many-to-one cascade="save-update, delete"
                    class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.Column"
                    column="target_column_id" name="targetColumn" />
                -->
                <property name="targetColumn" column="target_column" type="string"></property>
                <property name="templateName" column="template_name" type="string"></property>
                <!--
                    <bag name="targetColumnNames" cascade="save-update"
                    table="input_possible_columns_map"> <key
                    column="input_control_id"></key> <element column="column_name"
                    not-null="true" type="string" /> </bag>
                -->
                <!--<bag name="possibleValues" cascade="save-update" table="input_possible_values_map">
                    <key column="input_control_id" />
                    <many-to-many
                        class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.uicontrols.PossibleValue"
                        column="value" />
                </bag>
                --><property name="seperator" column="seperator" type="string" />
                <many-to-one name="refTable" cascade="refresh"
                    class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.Table" column="ref_table_id" lazy="false">
                </many-to-one>
                <many-to-one name="targetTable" cascade="refresh"
                    class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.Table" column="target_table_id" />
                <property name="version" type="string" column="version_id"></property>
                <property name="currentDate" type="date" column="curr_date"></property>
                <property name="currentIP" type="string" column="current_ip"></property>
                <many-to-one name="currentUser"
                    class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.domain.common.User" cascade="refresh"
                    column="current_user_id"></many-to-one>
                <property name="latestDate" type="date" column="latest_date"></property>
                <property name="latestIP" type="string" column="latest_ip"></property>
                <many-to-one name="latestUser"
                    class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.domain.common.User" cascade="refresh"
                    column="latest_user"></many-to-one>
                <property name="recordStatus" type="boolean" column="record_status"></property>
                <property name="portal" type="string" column="portal"></property>
                <many-to-one name="linkedColumn" cascade="refresh"
                    class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.Column" column="linked_column_name">
                </many-to-one>
                <many-to-one name="linkedMasterColumn" cascade="refresh"
                    class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.Column" column="linked_master_column">
                </many-to-one>
                <many-to-one name="linkedTable" cascade="refresh"
                    class="com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.Table" column="linked_master_id">
                </many-to-one>
            </joined-subclass>
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Focus on com.sampleproject.client.beansdm.metadata.uicontrols.InputControl joined-subclass mapping there is a field named btnName. Its working fine with 3.2.5 version but when i changed it to newer hibernate version it stops responding.

Is there any possible jar conflicts ?

Please help.

Thanking You,
Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Hibernate Version Comparison](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide36/diff?secondVersionNumber=5) guide states when moving from 3.5 to 3.6 that:

> However, for users still using hbm.xml
>   you should be aware that we chose to
>   use the
>   org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
>   used in AnnotationConfigration instead
>   of the older
>   org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
>   historically used on Configuration. 
>   This may cause naming mismatches; **one
>   known place where this is an issue is
>   if you rely on the naming strategy to
>   default the name of a association**
>   (many-to-many and collections of
>   elements) table.  If you find yourself
>   in this situation, you can tell
>   Hibernate to use the the legacy
>   org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
>   by calling
>   Configuration#setNamingStrategy and
>   passing it
>   org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy#INSTANCE

The `NamingStrategy` interface defines several methods like `String foreignKeyColumnName(String propertyName, String propertyEntityName, String propertyTableName, String referencedColumnName)`used to determine the names of columns and associations which are implemented by the [EJB3NamingStrategy](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/cfg/EJB3NamingStrategy.java.html).  I suggest you look at the implementation of these methods in the `EJB3NamingStrategy` class and see how it is transforming property names to column names.

It looks like hibernate is now adding the underscores to what it expects the column name to be in the DB via one these transformations, and is upset when it can't find the resultant column name 'btn_name' in your database.

Comment: Nice Answer...Can i create my own EJB3NamingStrategy by extending it and overriding methods and supplying somewhere to understand hibernate well.

Comment: What should be my final step ?? I have almost 190 tables and its nearly impossible to convert hbm to annotation for all of them. I appreciated your time and efforts thank you.

Comment: You do not have to change from hbm to annotations to use a different NamingStrategy.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy for details on how to implement a new NamingStrategy.  You could even extend the EJB3NamingStrategy just changing the namings which are causing grief.  I would also turn on the show_sql option in your configuration file so you can see exactly what commands hibernate is using to access your db.